# ext4 mysterious "No space left on device" error

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, nfs, ext4, fsck

Im having trouble with my ext4 filesystem. Im using this with NFS to make it available to remote machines. Now its showing a mysterious "No space left on device" error when im trying to `mkdir $name` but noting seems to help.
If i move or cp files (Size doesnt matter) this error doesnt show up.

I checked available space (over 400G)
I checked inodes (only 12% used)
I did a fsck and repaired errors.
I reindexed the filesystem with `fsck -D` and after that wasnt helpful i disabled `dir_index` completely. Like in [this Post](https://blog.merovius.de/2013/10/20/ext4-mysterious-no-space-left-on.html) suggests.

Maybe the fact, that this error only shows up on a few directories is helpful. Does ext4 has a max directory depth or something?

Comment: Have you deleted big files recently? If so, run `sudo lsof / | grep -i deleted` to investigate possible process still using those files.

Comment: @ManuelFlorian, no there was no deletion of big files. I also rebootet the machine. There is no open fh or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is, that there are too many extended acls on the directory. Took me a few days to check that.